# Target IE 9 AND less with conditional comments

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

First off I'm sorry if this has been answered already I just spent 45 minutes trying to find and answer and couldn't come across one that I felt sure about. I'm trying to use **flexbox** on my site and am trying to target IE 9 AND less for a fallback alternative.

I've seen some hacks and have seen people say to do this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="belowIE10.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

I've seen a lot of people say that doesn't work though. I'm assuming it's because conditional comments were dropped in 10 and internet explorer doesn't understand what `lt IE 10` is.

My best guess is checking for less than or equal to 9. I have a mac though and can't actually check this out without something like browserstack.

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>

<![endif]-->
```

**Does that work for IE9 and below?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE10 doesn't understand conditional comments, but that simply means it sees the `lt IE 10` and everything else inside as one giant HTML comment, as the syntax highlighting shows.

So there is no difference between `<!--[if lt IE 10]>` and `<!--[if lte IE 9]>`: IE10 will ignore both, and IE9 will match both conditions. You could even go with `<!--[if IE]>` and that wouldn't be any different.

Comment: Thanks Bolt Clock. I like the `if IE` the best... This was probably a stupid thought, but my main concern was whether older browsers like IE9 and less would understand what  `IE 10` was. I thought maybe since there wasn't support for conditional tags in IE10 than maybe older browsers wouldn't understand references to them either. So just out of curiosity... obviously I would never do this,  but could I assume then that `if lt IE 11`, `if lt IE 12`, etc. would also all work the same way that `if lt IE 10`, `if lte IE 9`, `if IE` do?

Comment: @Bryan Willis: Yes - IE performs numeric comparisons in that regard. I happen to use `if IE` on my own site.